# SSH sends environment variable, but to no effect

Tags: ssh, cygwin, environment-variables, suse, tcsh

I'm SSH'ing from Cygwin into an older SUSE machine. I use:

```
MyHost
    SetEnv FOO=bar
    SendEnv BAZ
```

in my `./ssh/config` file, and run `export BAZ=bar` on my Cygwin machine before connection.

When I connect, the SSH client *does* try to set the two environment variables to `bar`, so it seems - but on the remote machine it's like they're gone...

Note: If it helps - the default shell for the account I'm logging into is tcsh.

Answer (score 4):

The SSH server's `sshd_config` (at `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`) has:

```
AcceptEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
AcceptEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
AcceptEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL
```

... and no other `AcceptEnv` commands. Since `AcceptEnv` requires specific server opt-in for every variable - my FOO-lish variables get rejected.